# Typescript. Не получается скопировать объект через Object.keys

Tags: typescript, объекты, typescript-типы

Есть два одинаковых объекта (obj1, obj2), нужно заполнить obj2 значениями из obj1, используя Object.keys. Код тут наипростейший, но как правильно решить ошибку типизации, я не знаю.

```
type TMap = {
    key1?: string;
    key2?: number;
}

const obj1: TMap = {
    key1: 'key1',
    key2: 1
}

const obj2: TMap = {}

const getKeys = Object.keys as <T>(obj: T) => [keyof T];

getKeys(obj1).forEach(key => {
    obj2[key] = obj1[key]; // Error
})
```

Comment: Вопрос! где Вопрос!?

Comment: @qwabra "как правильно решить ошибку типизации". Там проблема в том, что при присвоении `obj2[key] = obj1[key]` справа выходит объединённый тип значений всех ключей, что не подходит конечно для присвоения. Но спорно, что это ошибка типизации, здесь с типизацией всё верно, но есть нюанс. Ситуация частая.

Comment: Объяви ключ как any и не парься. Или  'keyof TMap'

Comment: @qwabra, ключ и так так объявлен, тут это не поможет, потому что `obj1[key]` дает тип union всех типов значений, и если некоторые типы не совместимы и происходит ошибка